# Is there anywhere I can read about the byte arrangements for GIFS?

Tags: gif, animated-gif

So for example, there's a site that tells me what the byte arrangements are for GIFs, for example, the first 7 bytes are the HEADER, next 6 bytes are description information etc etc?

I am looking for both static and animated GIF images.

Bonus points if you can supply a site that covers other images.

It's so I know how to correctly interpret the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search in the wiki [a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Interchange_Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Interchange_Format) got [a link](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/GIF/spec-gif89a.txt).